# Proposition Negation Help: $ \forall_x[p(x) \to \neg q(x)] $

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Negate and simplify the the quantified statement: $$\forall_x[p(x) \to \neg q(x)] $$

My answer:

$ \neg\forall_x[p(x) \to \neg q(x)] \tag 1$

$ \exists_x\neg [p(x) \to \neg q(x)] \tag 2$

$ \exists _x[\neg p(x)\leftrightarrow \neg(¬q(x))] \tag 3$

$ \exists _x[\neg p(x) \leftrightarrow q(x)] \tag 4$

My answer is not correct. I believe I have made a mistake (I am unsure how to deal with the implies symbol), and, hence, clarification would be much obliged.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Can you make a truth table for $\neg (A\to B)$?

Comment: @Git Gud, I believe this is the truth table. How do I apply that?
\begin{align}
&0  \ \\  
&0 & \\
&1 \\
&0 
&
\end{align}

Comment: That's not a table, that's a column, but let us assume you're thinking correctly. Can you now build the truth table for $\neg A\leftrightarrow \neg B$?

Comment: $$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
A & B & ¬A & ¬B &¬A↔¬B  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Good work. Now compare the truth tables for $\neg (A\to B)$ and $\neg A\leftrightarrow \neg B$. Are these columns equal? Can you see how this relates to your answer? Can you now tell where you made a mistake, even if you don't understand it?

Comment: Remember that an implication, $A\to C$, is falseified exactly when the antecedant, $A$, is true and the consequent, $C$, is not.$$\neg(A\to B)\iff A\wedge\neg B$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transition from (2) to (3) is incorrect.  Using $\lnot p\leftrightarrow q \equiv (\lnot p \to q) \land (q \to \lnot p)$:

(2)[image] $\quad \not\equiv \quad$ (3/4)[image]

**Instead, we can to use  the definition of implication: $a \to b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$:

[image] $\quad \equiv \quad$ [image]

---

$$\neg\forall_x[p(x) \to \neg q(x)] \tag 1$$

$$\exists_x\neg [p(x) \to \neg q(x)] \tag 2$$

$$\exists_x\neg[\lnot p(x) \lor \lnot q(x)]\tag {(3) Definition: implication}$$

$$\exists_x [\lnot \lnot p(x) \land \lnot\lnot q(x)]\tag{(4) DeMorgan's Rule}$$

$$\exists_x [p(x)\land q(x)]\tag {(5) Double Negation}$$

---

[image] $\quad \equiv\quad $  [image]
   $\quad \equiv\quad$ [image]